# Storyboard performSegueWithIdentifier not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am currently trying to change to Image Preview View Controller to Select a Brand View. I first was trying with a segue.  The Storyboard Segue is set correctly without spell mistakes but doesn't work. 
[image]

In my Image Preview View Controller code I have

```
-(void)brandButtTapped:(UIButton*)button{

    NSLog(@"brandbuttTapped");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imagePreviewVCtoBrandSearchVC" sender:self];

}
```

However I am getting an error saying

'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'imagePreviewVCtoBrandSearchVC'''

What is wrong with my code? Thank you if you want to see anymore code please feel free to ask!

Comment: You can just ctrl-drag from the button to the destination VC and avoid the action method altogether

Comment: You setup the segue on some object or the viewcontroller?

Comment: Please check edit. It appears your ctrl+drag from your VC to your button, and not your button to your VC.

Comment: You say that code is in ImagePreviewViewController but the button is in the SelectABrand scene.  What causes the code to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I noticed you have a segue going the wrong way from your `brandButton`. Connect you segue from your brandButton and drag to your VC, not from your VC to your brandButton.

**RE-EDIT**

You don't appear to have anything that will deliver a response to call the code correctly; A button. If you did, you would not have to code anything to demand a transition back, because the segue would automatically perform.

Try embedding your TableViewController in a UINavigationController by selecting your TableView --> Select from the Menu at the top of screen Editor --> Select Embed In --> Select NavigationController.

This way you won;t have to worry about coding a transition back, you will have the option to return built in.

Otherwise, continue with code below.

**THEN**

Either try:

```
//note YOU HAVE NOT INCLUDED .storyboard
// Get the storyboard from the main bundle - check the name to confirm:
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
[storyboard performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imagePreviewVCtoBrandSearchVC" sender:self];
```

OR Try presenting the view controller. Name your view you wish to change to - Select your second view. Then select the StoryBoard editor and name your selected VC:

[image: name your VC]

Then code your button to change views like so:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

//animated can be NO
```

Comment: I don't think a storyboard can perform a segue.  The receiver needs to be a view controller.

Comment: It's wrong. There is no method like self.storyboard performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya it was correct. read my second answer. This is a little outdated now. Second should still work fine. This answer would not have been accepted otherwise.